# Can I be using Steam while someone else is redeeming a Steam giftcard on my account?

Tags: steam

What if someone's playing a game on Steam and another person is on the same account redeeming a gift card at the same time?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Why does your friend have access to your account?

Comment: I have no other ways to communicate with him anymore for a long time. All that I'm asking is that if he was trying to put it for me when I'm playing , would it do? And I don't have anything valuable for him to steal like credit card info and purchased games. All I have is free games

Comment: @SuperiorAsian If you can give him your password, he can just as easily give you the code, surely?

Comment: I gave him my account password ,but like what I said its too late to tell him now ,all I told him was to enter the gift card

Comment: @SuperiorAsian Then let's hope he does rather than, say, changing the password and stealing the account.

Comment: I trust him on not doing that

Comment: So as long as we don't play the same games on the same account nothing goes wrong

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're not trying to play two games at once, you can log into the same account from multiple locations. You (or your friend) can redeem the giftcard on one device while you play on the other.

However, there is **no reason** to do this. Your friend can just as easily give you the gift card or its code. They can also purchase games for you as gifts. Neither of these would require your friend accessing your Steam account, which is a massive security risk.